# Android: cannot instantiate the type httpclient

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I am getting an error with the following line of code

`HttpClient Client= new HttpClient`, event I have add  `httpclient-4.2.3.jar`  to my project.

I have tried rewriting it as `HttpClient Client= new DefaultHttpClient`. But it solves the problem and creates a new error with other methods (in `executeMethod()`).

**This is my code :**

```
    public static String POSTUpload(String url, String foto){
    InputStream inputStream=null;
    String result="";
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    PostMethod  method = new PostMethod(url);

    //set JSON ke hhtp post entity
//  File file_foto= new File(foto);
//  FileEntity fe_foto=new FileEntity(file_foto, "image/jpeg");
    method.setRequestEntity(new FileRequestEntity(new File(foto), "multipart/form-data"));
//  se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
//  httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

    try {
        int status = httpClient.executeMethod(method);
        System.out.println("HTTP status " + method.getStatusCode()
                + " creating con\n\n");
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }finally { 
          method.releaseConnection(); 
    }
}
```

is there anyone know why this is happen? Please Help

Comment: What is the error with `executeMethod` ?

Comment: try this        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);                          HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

   StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
   int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
   Log.e("Status code =", ""+statusCode);

Comment: @javaLearner its because error in `HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();`